# How to ignore the '\n' character in the input

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I need to make the program in such a way that when the return key is entered it  continues with the program and prints the initial lines again.

I tried to resolve it with (case '\n') but that didn't work and I tried some getchar() variants but I had the same issue.

```
    void main()
{
char nameA[100];
char nameB[100];
char command;
int height;
int quit = 1;

struct node *ring1 = NULL;
struct node *ring2 = NULL;

while(quit)
{
    printf("command? ");
    scanf("%c", %command, 1);
    
    switch (command)
    {
        case 'q':
            printf("bye\n");
            quit = 0;
            break;
            
        case 't':
            printf("name? ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]", nameA);
            printf("height? ");
            scanf(" %d", &height);
            
            ring1 = insert_tail(ring1, nameA, height);
            break;
            
        case '\n':
            break;
        
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

What I want to be able to print is

> command?
>
> command? ...

The problem is that if I use " %c" I will ignore the new line and if I use "%c" the output will look like:

> command?
>
> command? ...

but in the case that let's say I use the 't' command in my code the result will look like

> command? t
>
> name? Everest
>
> height? 8848
>
> command? command?

How can I fix that ? I assume the problems is because I actually enter two characters, the "t" and "\n" but I have no clue how to get around that.

Comment: `scanf("%c", %command, 1);` is quit incorrect.  Try `scanf("%c", &command);`

Comment: Might use `scanf("%c%*[^\n]%*c", & command)` but it looks horrible and may fail

Comment: @anatolyg `scanf("%c%*[^\n]%*c", & command)` with input `"t\n"` will leave `'\n'` in `stdin` for the next `scanf()` call.  `"%*c"` is not used when `"%*[^\n]"` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to ignore the '\n' character in the input

After all commands, except the bare `'\n'`, consume the rest of the line.

In the `t` case, it is the `'\n'` after the entered `height` that the causes the issue.  Consume it before looking for a new command.

```
while(quit) {
    printf("command? ");
    scanf("%c", &command);
    switch (command) {
      ...
    }
    if (command != '\n') {
      int ch;
      while ((ch = getchar()) != `'\n'`) && (ch != EOF)) {
        ;
      }
    }
}
```

---

Tip: Consider using `fgets()` for user input and avoid using `scanf()`.